# SQL query to update column of one table with reference of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Update the id column in `tableB` with the id in `tableA` where the reference is counties. If the countries match then the id should be populated in `tableB`.

Refer to the screen shots for reference.

TableB:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW8Ra.jpg)

TableA :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jirbq.jpg)

I tried the queries but couldn't solve it.

```
**update tableB set Id  from tableB,tableA where tableA.countries=tableB.country;**

**update  tableB set Id=(select id from   tableA where countries=(select countries from tableA ))**
```

Comment: sql server manageemnt studio 2012

Comment: My god, please use a spell checker before you hit submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try this query

```
UPDATE
    tableB
SET
    tableB.ID = A.ID
FROM
    tableB B
INNER JOIN
    tableA A
ON 
    B.country = A.countries
```